# What is the difference between loadu/lddqu and assignment operator?

Tags: c, sse, simd, intrinsics

I am using SIMD vector to do some computations, and curious the difference of them, as followings.

```
__m128i vector2 = vector1;
__m128i vector2 = _mm_loadu_si128(&vector1);
```

So, what's the difference of above two statements?

Comment: The second one is like writing `x = *&y` - it's extra complicated for no reason.  (Assuming `vector1` has type `__m128i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Peter Cordes said in his comment, if `vector1` really is a `__m128i` it's just unnecessarily complicated.

However, that's not the use case for `_mm_loadu_si128`.  While the type of the argument is `__m128i const*`, that's really more about a lack of good options and poor decisions.

`_mm_loadu_si128` is really meant to load any 16 bytes of data into a vector register.  If you want to load data which is already aligned to 16 byte boundaries you should use `_mm_load_si128` instead.  If your data isn't aligned to 16 byte boundaries it's not *really* a `__m128i`, so the type of the parameter is misleading at best.

The reason Intel (or whoever) chose to use `__m128i const*` isn't completely clear, but to be honest there aren't a lot of good options.  `int const*` wouldn't really make sense because what we're trying to load isn't always 32-bit signed integers.  They could have made an `_mm_loadu_epi8`, `_mm_loadu_epi16`, `_mm_loadu_epi32`, etc., but even that wouldn't be quite right because the data doesn't need to be aligned to `_Alignof(int)`, `_Alignof(short)`, *etc.*, though `char` actually work well here.

The right choice would probably be to make the argument `void*`, but I guess Intel wanted to signal that they really wanted 16 bytes of data.  `char mem_addr[16]` would be okay in C99+, but not in C++, and while SSE2 came out at around the same time as C99 many compilers didn't support C99 (MSVC still doesn't!).

Basically, for this function, ignore the types of the parameters and read the description.

Comment: Intel did correctly pick `void*` for their intrinsics since AVX-512, including new non-AVX-512 ones like `_mm_loadu_si32(void*)` that fills the previously missing gap of an unaligned strict-aliasing-safe `movd` intrinsic.  (Previously you were probably supposed to just point a misaligned `int*` at stuff, which is super broken.)  `__m128i*` is just dumb, requiring a cast in every use.  It seems obviously bad to me, especially the confusing requirement to create a misaligned `__m128i*` for `_mm_loadu_si128`.